# How to fluidly scroll a background image with CSS

Tags: html, css

So I have a background image that is a bit taller and wider than normal browsers.
I'd like to be able to have it so that it scrolls it proportionately to the size of the screen. Since it is longer than normal, i'd also like it to scroll down gradually as the user scrolls down the page until the user reaches the bottom.

To put it simply, I think 
Let's assume the side height is 1000px, and my image is 1500, i'd like the top to start a the page and be sized so it fits the user's screen, however the bottom 500 i'd like to have scroll at half the speed so as the user scrolls down it slowly scrolls till it reaches the bottom.

I'll find a simpler website later, this conept is hard to put into words and google.
If anyone understands, please help!

I need to use css or something

Comment: http://inner.geek.nz/javascript/parallax/ As you can see here, the background scrolls at a different speed than the page. I'd like a similar idea to happen with my website, only instead of scrolling fast, it scrolls more slowly, as my website is rather on the large side (Vertically) but as the user gets to the bottom of the page, so does the image.

Comment: Not necessarily, but i'd like to keep it as css as possible. no flash or anything proprietary. Sort of like the option where it will allow you to not scroll it and make it proportionate, only slowly scrolling.

Comment: Your example -- Parallax Backgrounds -- doesn't just exemplify your desired effect, it explains itself quite well. Why not use that???

Comment: Because in that example it's scrolling too fast, i need it basically to fill the website space proportionately to the user's browser, and scroll baed upon that independent of the content.

Comment: Sor of like paralex scrolling, only.... vertical? as opposed to horizontal.

Comment: Detecting browser scroll require javascript. Solely CSS is not possible as I know of. The theory is like this. Supposing you have a page with height > screen, otherwise it's pointless to scroll. Detect the height of the background image. Determine the percentage of window scroll then deduct how much pixel the background image should be moved.

Answer (score 1):

2 Things you should make before posting.

1. **Show some code / attempts**
2. **Inspect your sources.**

As far as I could see on the website you have provided, they are using simple one image which is `400px x 400px` and the other which is `53px x 54px` and it repeats both ways (height and width).

This is the background image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [geek.nz](http://inner.geek.nz/javascript/parallax/clouds.png))</sub>

On the back of that PNG image is the following image:

[image]

It is a GIF image.

They use the following on their CSS, **which you should have had a go on it!**

```
#ground {
background-image: url(bg-green.gif);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#clouds {
background-image: url(clouds.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
padding: 5em 0;
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?